# Generating and removing elements from the list

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to make a simple component which generates a list containing 100 elements. Each element should contain a button. If user clicks the button the element is removed from DOM. Additionally every 3-third element should be clickable. After click some action should be called, for example changing its layout.

I've created a button, which generates a list. Now I have problem to remove elements, while clicking on the button.

```js
let addButton = document.getElementById('btn');

addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {


    let element = document.createElement("button");
    let textElement = document.createTextNode("Click");
    let classElement = document.createAttribute("class");

    classElement.value = "buttonClick";

    let paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    let textParagraph = document.createTextNode("List element");
    let classParagraph = document.createAttribute("class");

    classParagraph.value = "paragraphList"

    let number = i + 1;

    paragraph.innerText = "List element number " + number;
    element.innerText = "Click";

    addButton.appendChild(paragraph);
    addButton.appendChild(element);

  };
});


let buttonRemove = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonClick");

buttonRemove.addEventListener('click', function() {


});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <button id="btn">Generate list</button>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `let buttonRemove = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonClick");` buttonRemove is a live node collection, not a single button. So you need to loop over all  those buttons and add the event to it. Or put the event on the list itself and work with event.target so you only have to add the event once. PS: If you use a actual unordered list `<ul>` or ordered list `<ol>` as the wrapper for a label and button, you'll probably have an easier time navigating the elements compared to having alternating buttons and labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign an ID to each of the elements with

`element.setAttribute('id','button'+i);`
where i is the counter in the for loop

and then remove the button with javascript by
`node.remove(button4);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you're attaching the button and the paragraph elements directly to the DOM. You should group them inside a div to make an entry clickable using divName.addEventListener("click", function);
To select every third element you can use the modulo operator % which returns the remainder of a division.

```js
let addButton = document.getElementById('btn');

addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    let container = document.createElement("div");
    let element = document.createElement("button");
    let paragraph = document.createElement("p");

    let number = i + 1;

    paragraph.innerText = "List element number " + number;
    element.innerText = "Click";
    document.body.appendChild(container);
    container.appendChild(paragraph);
    container.appendChild(element);
    element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.target.parentElement.remove();
    });
    if (number % 3 == 0) {
      container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        console.log("one of those third elements");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Generate list</button>
```